# After updating buildToolsVersion 24.0.2 I run my project so I am not showing layout views, layout should be blank

Tags: android

This is my dependencies

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.12"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    //        transitive = true;
    //    }
        compile files('libs/bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
        /*compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:24.2.0'*/
        compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
        compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.32'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main_screen" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/navigationViewBg"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_for_img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image_bg"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />

            <com.starofservice.android.activity.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_UserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Ivo Dimitrov"
                android:textColor="@color/textWhite" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/shape" android:id="@+id/sos_image" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@color/navigationViewBg"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/logon_signup_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_login_menu_bg">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/logon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:background="@drawable/login_icon"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/main_Screen_LogIn_SignUp_text_Color"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
                android:text="@string/main_Screen_LogIn_SignUp_text"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/switch_to_pro_client"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="#f9f9f9">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/logon_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/switch_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_switch_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/label_switch_to_client"
                android:textColor="@color/textDarkGray"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I upgrading buildToolsVersion 23.0.3 to buildToolsVersion 24.0.2 everything should be fine, without any error but problem is when I run the project mainactivity layout views are not showing, I am putting login activity layout is loading but it's not showing.

Comment: If possible put screen shot of that.

Comment: BuildToolsVersion 24.0.2 requires Java 1.8 or above. Have you installed and set it correctly?

Comment: There should only be one root node in your layout. You have an `include` and a `NavigationView`. I'm surprised it worked for you prior to 24

Comment: yes i install java 1.8

Comment: @tushar sorry i am not putting some layout part here but parent view is android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.